# Não consigo inserir o banco

Tags: php, mysql

Estou usando o bootstrap no meu primeiro projeto do colégio e estou com dificuldade na interação PHP, HTML e MySQL

Além de não estar conseguindo inserir no banco, preciso inserir no `tipousuario_idtipousuario` os `values` respectivos que estão no `select`

Exemplo:

```
1 -> Professor  
2 -> Técnico  
3 -> Administrador
```

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="container-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="header">
                            <h4 class="title"></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content">
                            <form action="CadastrarUsuario.php" method="POST">
                                  <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Nome</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Nome Reduzido</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome Reduzido" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                      <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Cpf</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="sem traços ou pontos" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Senha</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Repete a Senha</label>
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Repete a Senha" >
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Tipo de Usuário</label>
                                            <select  class="form-control" >
                                                <option value="0">Selecione o tipo usuário: </option>
                                                <option value="1"> Professor</option>
                                                <option value="2"> Técnico</option>
                                                <option value="3"> Administrador</option>
                                            </select>   
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-left">Cadastrar Usuário</button>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Aqui está o php:

```
            <?php include 'VerificarSession2.php'?>
            <?php
            try{
                include 'Conexao.php';
                include 'registrarusuario.php';

                $nome = $_POST['nomeusuario'];
                $nomereduzido = $_POST['nomereduzido'];
                $cpf= $_POST['cpfusuario'];
                $senha = $_POST['senha'];
                $tipousuario_idtipousuario = $_POST['tipousuario_idtipousuario'];
                $descricao= $_POST['descricaousuario'];
                $idtipousuario= $_POST['idtipousuario'];

            if(isset($_POST['nomeusuario'])){

                $nome = $_POST['nomeusuario'];

            //Cadastrar Alunos na tabela 'alunos' e Disciplinas na tabela 'aluno_disciplina'
                //Inserir aluno 
            $stmt = $conexao->prepare("insert into usuario(nomeusuario,nomereduzido, cpfusuario,senha,tipousuario_idtipousuario) values (?,?,?,?,?)");



            $stmt -> bindParam(1,$nome);
            $stmt -> bindParam(2,$nomereduzido);
            $stmt -> bindParam(3,$cpf);
            $stmt -> bindParam(4,$senha);
            $stmt -> bindParam(5,$tipousuario_idtipousuario);

            $stmt->execute(); 
            //Busca o ID do aluno inserido
            $stmt = $conexao->prepare("SELECT tipousuario_idtipousuario FROM usuario WHERE idtipousuario = ?");

                $stmt -> bindParam(1,$idtipousuario);



                    $stmt->execute();

                    if($stmt->rowCount()<4){




                    $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll();
                    foreach($resultado as $linha){ 
                     $Idaluno = $linha['idaluno'];



                    }

                    }




            <!-- for($i=0;$i<count($cpfusuario);$i++){

            $stmt = $conexao->prepare("insert into aluno_disciplina(aluno_idaluno,disciplina_iddisciplina,disciplinaativo) values (?,?,1)");
            $stmt -> bindParam(1,$Idaluno);
            $stmt -> bindParam(2,$cpfusuario[$i]);

             $stmt->execute();

            }
             -->





            $_SESSION['mensagem'] = "Usuário cadastrado com sucesso!";
                    echo "<script language= 'JavaScript'>
            location.href='../mensagem.php?msg=Cadastrado&url=registraralunos.php'
            </script>"; 






            }
            else{

             $_SESSION['erromatricula'] = "Você deve selecionar ao menos uma Disciplina!";
                    echo "<script language= 'JavaScript'>
            location.href='../SelecionarDisciplinas.php?nome=".$Nome."&matricula=".$Matricula."'
            </script>";   


            } 


            }catch(PDOException $e){
            echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: Aconselho utilizar OO nesse projeto, procedural e muito ruim de manutencao. Mais bem qual exception esta aparecendo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao que tudo indica esta passando POSTS que não existem, afinal seus inputs não tem name e o seu select também não. No seu campo

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ... >
```

Faça com que eles tenham names que serão respectivos ao seu POST, como irei mostrar abaixo

```
 <input type="text"  name ="nome" class="form-control" placrholder="Nome">
 <input type="text"  name ="nome_reduzido" class="form-control" placrholder="Nome Reduzido">
 <input type="text"  name ="cpf" class="form-control" placrholder="Cpf">
 <input type="text"  name ="senha" class="form-control" placrholder="nome">
 <select name="id_tipousuario" class="form-control">
```

Seu post ficará assim

```
$nome  = $_POST['nome'];
$nome_reduzido  = $_POST['nome'_reduzido];
$cpf  = $_POST['cpf'];
$senha  = $_POST['senha'];
$id_tipousuario  = $_POST['id_tipousuario'];
```

Altere também o seu insert para que as variáveis fiquem equivalentes aos POSTS de uma forma que não exista conflito na passagem dos dados e consiga inseri-los, como irei mostrar abaixo

```
$stmt -> bindParam(1,$nome);
$stmt -> bindParam(2,$nome_reduzido);
$stmt -> bindParam(3,$cpf);
$stmt -> bindParam(4,$senha);
$stmt ->bindParam(5,$id_tipousuario);
```

Ja adequei os names e os POSTS para que você consiga incluir no seu projeto, se persistir outro erro poste aqui no comentário

Answer (score 3):

Você não colocou nome nos inputs. Logo não captura o valor enviado pelo form e não consegue inserir no banco. Todo campo de inserção precisa ser identificado com o atributo name.

```
<input type="text" name="sobrenome" placeholder="Insira seu sobrenome">
```

E para capturar no PHP você utiliza o mesmo nome que colocou no atributo name, que no nosso caso é sobrenome:

```
$sobrenome = $_POST['sobrenome'];
```